# HttpHostConnectException 10.0.2.2:8080 refused

Tags: android, apache, tomcat, http-post

On executing the following statement the app does not respond for a minute and then following logcat message occurs :

```
     HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8080/webapp/CreateUser");
```

logcat -

```
 org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.2.2:8080 refused
```

PS - i've tried using "ip address" , 127.0.0.1 AND localhost instead of 10.0.2.2 still the same case.

Also the permissions for INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE are also in the manifest file.

Comment: Are you using emulator or a physical device?

Comment: The ip address will not work. 127.0.0.1 and localhost will point to the server on the emulator itself. 10.0.2.2 is the correct way. On your computer are you able to access the webserivce ?

Comment: i am using a physical device
Yes  , when i run the servlet only from netbeans , it opens

Comment: What network is your device connected to?

Comment: Sorry ? what network as in ?

Comment: Is your device connected to the internet? (through wireless for example)

Comment: yea , its connected to wifi

Comment: Can you access the URL from your browser?

Comment: nope , its not opening from the mobile's browser

Comment: Do you have this in your manifest file? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />` ?

Comment: nope , still no luck :/

Comment: Also, have you retrieved your ip from the cmd using the ipconfig command?

Comment: haha true that , maybe i should run on the emulator virtually once , just to see if it helps . . .

Comment: yes , retrieved my ip from that command .

Comment: Go to your cmd and use the ipconfig to find the ip to your computer . It should look something like this 192.168.0.102  It should be next to the IPv4 Address

Comment: yea , i've written in the question only , i tried using my ip address instead of 10.0.2.2

Comment: The 10.0.0.2 is used within an emulator running on the same host as your webserver, meaning if you're testing on a smartphone and not the Android emulator program it wont work for you. Maybe you should try changing it again after all the solutions above.

Comment: yup did just that , it worked !! Thanks for the information . So is there anyway to run it on smartphone though ?

Comment: Yes, using the ip haha. I'm not quite sure why it doesn't work on your smartphone. I am currently also developing an android app using my smartphone and it works. Your wifi is turned on but does it have internet connection? Oh well. Maybe once you restart everything it will work. If you do work around the problem and find a solution feel free to post your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay , the problem has been solved .

As answered by both Codemon and Jayesh , in order to use real device to run the app from Android Studio , you have to use the ip address of the server in place of 10.0.2.2 and make sure your phone device and server are in the same network:-

```
  HttpPost httpPost = new   HttpPost("http://192.168.1.53:8080/webapp/CreateUser");
```

I guess my internet connection was not stable , so ip was changing and thats why it didn't work before.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Your server code mostly will be accessible on the local and Wifi network if you have turned on sharing and network discovery on your system.

For the physical device to see this server it has to be on the same network. Also you need to use the IP address of your server.

Comment: i am actually using the real device(via usb) as an emulator to run the app from android studio.

Comment: How is the device connected to the internet?

Comment: its connected via wifi

Comment: And your server is on the same network as this Wifi? If yes, Can you access this URL from the browser of your phone? Use the IP address of your system.

Comment: Windows system? Check your network discovery and sharing options. Ensure that the IP and port number are correct

Comment: yup windows , i've even disabled the firewall